# Annotations multiplication with filtering on many to many relationship

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

I have models:

```
class Tag:
    name

class User:
    tags = M2M to Tag
    ...

class Bill:
    id
    tags = M2M to Tag
    ...


class BillRow:
    bill = FK to Bill, related_name='rows'
    quantity
    ...
```

And I want for an User filter the Bills on Tags and annotate with some aggregates, for example Count of rows, Sum of quantity...

```
Bill.objects.filter(tags__in=user_tags).annotate(row_count=Count("rows"))
```

The problem is that if User and Bill have more tags in common (some User U1 has user_tags ['T1', 'T2', 'T3'] and some Bill B1 has ['T2', 'T3', 'T4']) the resulting query is using an inner join on the Tag table for the filter and it duplicates in this example the row_count annotation, because for each row of B1 there are 2 joined rows (for both of the shared tags) which satisfy the condition.
Is there some solution for this type of annotation specifically in Django ORM, but more broadly what would be the optimal approach in SQL to obtain the correct results?

UPDATE: As @BrianD pointed out for Count the solution is the distinct=True attribute:

```
Bill.objects.filter(tags__in=user_tags).annotate(row_count=Count("rows", distinct=True))
```

but I need a the Sum annotation also:

```
Bill.objects.filter(tags__in=user_tags).annotate(row_count=Count("rows", distinct=True), row_sum=Sum("rows__quantity"))
```

There the distinct attribute isn't working because it just sums the distinct different quantities, not the quantities in distinct rows.

UPDATE 2:
Given mentioned example of B1 and U1 the query is:

```
Bill.objects.filter(tags__in=['T1', 'T2', 'T3']).annotate(row_sum=Count("rows__quantity"))
```

I this case the filter needs an inner join of Bill to Tag on common tags ('T2' and 'T3' specifically), and another join to rows. Suppose B1 has rows R1 and R2 with quantities 10 and 20. The row_sum annotation for B1 should correctly be 30, but it is 60, because the first join duplicates the number of records for B1 (as 2 tags are shared/satisfy the condition), and even if the final `group by` removes the duplications of bill rows it still counts the quantities of it's rows double (because it operates before the `group by`).

Comment: Try to use `Count("rows", distinct=True)`

Comment: @BrianD Thanks, you are right, for Count the solution is that simple, I should have used Sum in the example, which is what I need also.

Comment: Can you share some sample data? `row_sum=Sum("rows__quantity")` should sum all the related row's quantities, not just distinct quantities.